# Using destructuring is not assigning in a forEach loop. It is assigning if I write object.property

Tags: javascript, foreach, destructuring

I'm taking in a recursively generated object that looks like this

```
optionObject = {text:'some text', subOptions:[array of option Objects with their own subOptions]
arrayOfObjects=[optionObject1,optionObject2,...optionObjectn]
```

If an option has no subOptions, then subOptions has a value of null.

I'm trying to assign a value 'depth' to each object, which will relate to how many levels deep we are in the object (IE optionObjects 1-n have a depth of 0. Each of their subOptions have a depth of 1. Each subOption of those subOptions has a depth of 2, etc.)

I'm doing this recursively, as the object can be arbitrarily deep.

```
const assignDepth = function (arrayOfObjects) {
    arrayOfObjects.forEach((object) => {
        object = {
            ...object,
            depth: 0
        }
        object = formatSubOptions(object)
    })
    return arrayOfObjects
}

formatSubOptions = function (option) {
    const depth = option.depth + 1
    if (option.subOptions) {
        return option.subOptions.forEach((subOption) => {
            subOption = {
                ...subOption,
                depth: depth
            }
            subOption = formatSubOptions(subOption)
        })
    } else {
        return option
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, the depth values are not being assigned when I use destructuring. However, if I change my format to something like

```
option.depth = 0
```

or

```
subOption.depth = depth
```

my values are persistent and I receive the values I would expect to receive. Obviously it's not a big deal if I'm only changing one attribute, but in the future, I may need to add many more. Can anyone explain why destructuring is not assigning the new depth field?

Comment: Assigning a new value to `object` will not affect the actual object in the array; it just changes the value of the parameter.

Comment: It seems like you are expecting the assignment of `object =` in the `assignDepth` to somehow replace the element in the array, but as you've written it, *it does not*.  Instead of `arrayOfObjects.forEach`, consider using `arrayOfObjects.map` and return the new value of each element in the callback.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still missing something. I tried updating to a map statement, but the destructuring is still not assigning as I'd expect. 

I think I'm primarily unclear on what the difference is between assigning object.depth = val vs. object = {...object,depth:val}. Does forEach view the second one as an overwriting action and prevent it from executing behind the scenes?

Comment: One modifies the property of the original object.  The other creates a brand new object.  Try it. `a = b = {msg: 'before'};  a.msg = 'after';  console.log(b);`  vs.  `a = b = {msg: 'before'}; a = {...a: msg: 'after'};  console.log(b);`

Comment: Are you aware of why `someArray.forEach(object => { object = 99; })` doesn't actually replace any of the the elements of the array with 99?  Same reason `function(foo) { foo = 99; }` doesn't modify the thing that you originally passed into `foo`.

Comment: Apparently I am unaware of why that won't work. I could swear that I'd mutated the argument in a forEach loop in the past, but my current experience suggests that I'm remembering inaccurately. I'm not seeing any mention of non-mutable arguments in the mozilla developer page. I hate to continue taking up your time, but why is that? I've always treated array.forEach as a sort of self-commenting for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're using this construct:

```
array.forEach(object => { object = 'something new' });
```

...and you're hoping that this will modify the elements of the array.  **It will not.**

However, If the elements of the array are objects, you can modify each of those objects like this:

```
array.forEach(object => { object.name = 'Fred' });
```

This will actually modify each object.

But the following **will not**:

```
array.forEach(object => { object = { name: 'Fred' }; });
```

This is the same as assigning `object = 'something new'`  It's just that you're assigning a brand new object.  The original object to which the array element refers hasn't changed.

For very similar reasons, the following will also **not work**:

```
array.forEach(object => { object = { ...object, name: 'Fred' }; });
```

What **will** work, is to assign a completely new array.

```
array = array.map(object => ( { ...object, name: 'Fred' } ));
```

This will create a new array, with new objects that all happen to have the name "Fred" and the other properties of the previous objects.

So to fix your scenario, instead of this:

```
const assignDepth = function (arrayOfObjects) {
    arrayOfObjects.forEach((object) => {
        object = {
            ...object,
            depth: 0
        }
        object = formatSubOptions(object)
    })
    return arrayOfObjects
}
```

Just use `map` to map each item to a new item.  This shows the technique:

```
const assignDepth = arrayOfObjects => 
    arrayOfObjects.map(object => formatSubOptions({ ...object, depth: 0 }));
```

Working example.  ***Note***: I'm only fixing `assignDepth` here.  You can use the technique to fix `formatSubOptions` the same way.  I'll provide a fake stand-in for `formatSubOptions`.

```js
const formatSubOptions = x => ({ ...x, formatted: true});

const assignDepth = arrayOfObjects =>
    arrayOfObjects.map(object => formatSubOptions({ ...object, depth: 0 }));

a = [ { msg: 'hello1', depth: 1 }, { msg: 'hello2', depth: 2 } ]
console.log(a);

a = assignDepth(a);
console.log(a);
```